# How should I get params directly in layout.js like page.js in app-router mode of next.js 14?

Tags: next.js, next.js14

I'm finishing a website with next.js, as a beginner with react and nextjs,
I now have a problem: How can I get params in layout.js as easily as in page.js?

```
// app/page.js
export default async function Home({ params }) {
    console.log('params:',params); // this params has true params, {...}
    return (
        <div>
            
        </div>
    );
}
```

```
// app/layout.js
export default async function Home({ params, children }) {
    console.log('params:',params); this params is empty, {};
return (
<html
lang='en'
className='light'
>
<body>
<Providers>
{children}
</Providers>
</body>
</html>
);
}
```

As described above, I hope to get params in layout.js,
Mainly url parameters, I need to request and render certain data through this parameter

Answer (score 0):

It seems your layout is named wrong. According to [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts)

> The top-most layout is called the Root Layout. This required layout is
> shared across all pages in an application. Root layouts must contain
> html and body tags.

the solution would be renaming to RootLayout [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#root-layout-required)

```
// app/layout.tsx
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```